# Using SpriteKit Without Physics or SKActions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I want to move nodes without using SKPhysicsBody or SKActions. Here is what I have

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    let deltaT = currentTime - timeLast
    node.position.y += CGFloat(deltaT * 3) //node is an SKShapeNode
    timeLast = currentTime
}
```

The node does not appear on the screen. If I remove this code, the default position is set to the center of the screen, which works fine. What is wrong with my approach above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that `timeLast` was initialized to 0, so `currentTime` has a value in the thousands, causing the node to be positioned off screen as soon as update is called